# How to create partiton between SSD and HDD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

How is SSD and Hdd divided in a Laptop having both? I have Hp-Omen which has 128gb ssd and 1tb HDD. The main problem is when I manually allocate space while install ubuntu, I don't understand which Drive to use. I created a partition in windows in "Disk 1" which had Data D(931gb) and a recovery mode(12gb). But it dosen't say whether partiton was created in Hdd or SSD.
I've been trying to install ubunt for about 4 times now and it gets stuck after restart and wont even restart after rebooting. I think The above mentioned issue might be the problem to Ubuntu not being able to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UBUNTU the ssd will have nvme0n[n1]p[n2] as device name and the hdd will have sd[c1][n2] where [n1] is the hard disk number, [n2] is the partition number, [c1] is a letter indicating the hard disk number. Mind that this is related to a HP Omen. Other systems might have an older ssd version: nvme is a M.2 SSD. That is a newer type of SSD.

Info from my hp omen:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238,5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVLB256HAHQ-000H1              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 413DE1FA-AC03-482C-8B9B-B2829FE8E8DC

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048   1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1026048   1288191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3   1288192 391913191 390625000 186,3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 391913472 500117503 108204032  51,6G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LM049-2GH1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4B296F6A-8910-4171-AE4A-944F8365F976
```

All windows partitions will have a label saying it is windows.

> I created a partition in windows in "Disk 1" which had Data D(931gb) and a recovery mode(12gb). But it dosen't say whether partiton was created in Hdd or SSD.

That is seen from windows so off topic. But the 931Gb will be the hdd (since the ssd is only 128Gb).

If you want to have the quickest boot: make spare space of 20Gb on the ssd for / including home. Make a partition on the hdd. Mount it with a name and use that to store your files.

Comment: hey thank you very much, BUT would you please elaborate the last lines. I don't get them. Are you trying to say that I should give 20GB for /  on SSD including the home partition. And swap area also on it. I think i already did that once. Ubuntu still won't start. Maybe problem is something else then, I guess.

Comment: Yes. And the 1st time have an usb where you install from inserted and boot into BIOS (press f10 during boot) and got to the boot options, pick the USB. That is the method to install Ubuntu through UEFI. Pick "something else" at the partition part of the install. During install mark the 20gb as / and give the partition you want for your files a mountpoint (mine is called /discworld). swap is a file nowadays and added by the system

Comment: Oh and my hp omen is a blast :-) I installed Ubuntu Budgie and everything worked. Even bluetooth (my old notebook I never got BT to work).  One thing that seemed to no work was the touchpad cuz it was sluggish in responding but, in hindsight, it probably had some kind of protective layer on it that needed to be wiped off. It is one hell of an amazing machine :-)

Comment: okay I did what u told me, and following thing happened. It again was first stuck at restart, then some terminal kind of thing was opened in which a series of errors were displayed. The I removed my pendrive(even though message was not shown). then it displayed message of removal of drive. But Nothing happend.So I powered down PC and turned it on again, opting for ubuntu and left it for two straight hours showing purple screen with ubuntu written on it. Nothing Happened. I was wondering that I recently found out that there was only 6mb of free space available on SSD.Should this be a problem.

Comment: Should this much less space on SSD be a problem for it, even though i created and allocated all the partitions on HDD which I am pretty sure about, Thanks to you.

Comment: Maybe. are you sure you allocated 20GB to the partition? Ubuntu requires 6Gb for the base install.

Comment: yeah I did. I am sorry but we are not getting anywhere. All I can do is ask you for a favor for sending me the exact steps of Installing the Ubuntu software the you did and explaining each step of allocating memory like where did we allocated and why. Or else I've tried almost everything, maybe i can send a mail to ubuntu help services and expect for an answer. Sorry i maybe asking too much. And thank you for being so much responsive. Peace.

Comment: How about https://jeanbruenn.info/2018/04/01/omen-hp-with-linux/ That is one of the links I found searching for hp omen before I bought it. Some of the info is old: you do not need a swap but the rest is good info.